# How To Remove Black Tea Stain from Carpet

Tags: cleaning, carpet, stain

I accidentally got black tea on a carpet, which has left a very visible stain. I tried cleaning the carpet with detergent, but it did not work. Does anyone have a good method for removing tea stains from a carpet?

Comment: What material is the carpet?  Removing tannin from wool is a whole different deal from taking it out of nylon or polyester.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vinegar to remove tea stains from carpet. Make a vinegar solution with the ratio of 1 cup of vinegar and two cup of water and wash the stain with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that ultraviolet light from sunlight will cause the stain to fade away on its own. If you want to hurry the process up, a variety of oxygen based bleaching agents are found in proprietary products; these work to break down the pigments in the stain, rendering it invisible

If attempting to clean the carpet using a wet solution, take care that the process doesn't cause whatever is under the carpet to become wet and stain the carpet from the other side. I once had a difficult job removing a tea stain that just seemed to grow and grow the more that I extended the cleaning patch, until I noticed that the brown coloration was being caused by the brown underlay getting wet and staining the carpet from the underside

Answer (score 1):

You can use salt water to remove tea stains from carpet.take one glass of water ,mix two spoons of salt and boiled it for ten minutes.after boiling throw the some quantity of water on the stain leave it for five minutes then rub it .